# wxpython set sizer background

Tags: python, background, wxpython

i am using wxpython and trying to make an background to a sizer without any success, i searched in google without any results.

i try it with this boxsizer

```
wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
```

Comment: A sizer is a layout tool and as such does not have a `background` attribute. Think of it as a container, into which widgets can be packed, along with how they should be displayed. The item/s that you put into the sizer, mostly, will have a background attribute.

Comment: Okay, then how i make an rectangle with white background that contains widgets?

Comment: As Rolf wrote: pack a widget into a sizer and define its background color. Could be a panel. If you want it to contain widgets, you must first add a sizer to this panel.

Answer (score 2):

I just use panels for this sort of thing. You can set the color of the panel several different ways: you can use a named color, a wx.Color object, a predefined wx.Color object like wx.RED or a tuple of 3 integers.

Here's a simple example:

```
import wx

class MyPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        self.SetBackgroundColour('white')

        main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        for number in range(5):
            btn = wx.Button(self, label='Button {}'.format(number))
            main_sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        self.SetSizer(main_sizer)


class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='Background colors')
        panel = MyPanel(self)
        self.Show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I wrote a little about this topic here:

- https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/09/03/wxpython-resetting-the-background-color/

You might also the wxPython wiki helpful:

- https://wiki.wxpython.org/GettingStarted